# Counter in BASH to count the times a number was entered?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script where you enter a number, then enter another value, if that value is the same as the first number entered, it adds to the cnt variable, then lets you input another number to check. It is supposed to repeated this until the two numbers do not match, and then print how many times the value occurred. I'm having trouble with the loop, after the second value is entered, it prints continuously:
**5 occurs 1 times**

```
    #!/bin/bash
read currVal
if [ -n $currVal ]; then
    cnt=1
    read val
    while [[ -n $val ]]
    do
            if [[ $val == $currVal ]]; then
                    cnt=$((cnt+1))
            else
                    echo "$currVal occurs $cnt times"
            fi
    done

fi
```

Comment: This is not correct as increment is only happening when numbers are equal hence 2 different numbers will always cause infinite loop. More importantly there is no break/exit inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @anubhava suggests, this modification works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
read currVal
cnt=1
val=$currVal
while [[ -n $val ]]
    do
    echo enter next
    read val
    if [[ $val == $currVal ]]; then
        cnt=$((cnt+1))
    else
        echo "$currVal occurs $cnt times"
    exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks to both of you. This did it for me. I see what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A variation what counts the entered values:

```
declare -A counts
while :
do
    read -r -p 'Enter number (or press enter to finish) > ' num
    [[ -z "$num" ]] && break
    ((counts["$num"]++))
done

for key in "${!counts[@]}"
do
    printf "entered %s: %s times\n" "$key" ${counts["$key"]}
done | sort -n
```